# Object with id "" is managed by a different Object Manager when calling several JpaRepository in the same methods in GAE's JPA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, spring-data-jpa, datanucleus

I'm using Google Apps Engine (GAE) with JPA's JpaRepository interfaces and Data Nucleus JPA implementation for GAE DataStore like that:

```
package com.appspot.repo;

import com.appspot.model.BusStop;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

/**
 * Created by eljah32 on 10/8/2017.
 */
public interface BusStopRepository extends JpaRepository<BusStop, String> {

}
```

and another repo

```
package com.appspot.repo;

import com.appspot.model.BusNode;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by eljah32 on 10/8/2017.
 */
public interface BusNodeRepository extends JpaRepository<BusNode, String> {
    List<BusNode> findTop1ByLatitude(double latitude);
    List<BusNode> findTop1ByLongitude(double longitude);
}
```

Then the model entities:

```
package com.appspot.model;

import org.datanucleus.api.jpa.annotations.Extension;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by eljah32 on 10/8/2017.
 */

@Entity
public class BusStop {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    public String key;

    @OneToOne
    public BusNode busNode;

    public String name;
    public String name_ru;
    public String name_tt;
    public String name_en;
}
```

and the other model

```
package com.appspot.model;

import org.datanucleus.api.jpa.annotations.Extension;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * Created by eljah32 on 10/8/2017.
 */

@Entity
public class BusNode {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private String id;
    @org.datanucleus.api.jpa.annotations.Index(unique = "false", name="LAT")
    public double latitude;
    @org.datanucleus.api.jpa.annotations.Index(unique = "false", name="LON")
    public double longitude;

}
```

and then I'm calling the jpa repo methods in the same method in the controller like that (see getBusStops()):

```
package com.appspot.controller;

import com.appspot.model.BusNode;
import com.appspot.model.BusRoute;
import com.appspot.model.BusStop;
import com.appspot.repo.BusNodeRepository;
import com.appspot.repo.BusRouteRepository;
import com.appspot.repo.BusStopRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by eljah32 on 10/8/2017.
 */

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bus")
@Transactional
public class BatchStorageController {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchStorageController.class);

    @Autowired
    BusNodeRepository busNodeRepository;

    @Autowired
    BusStopRepository busStopRepository;

    @Autowired
    BusRouteRepository busRouteRepository;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/nodes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<BusNode> getBusRoutes() {
        BusNode busNode=new BusNode();
        busNode.latitude=50.4;
        busNode.longitude=45.5;
        BusNode busNode2=new BusNode();
        busNode2.latitude=50.5;
        busNode2.longitude=45.3;
        busNodeRepository.save(busNode);
        busNodeRepository.save(busNode2);
        return busNodeRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/nodes/{latitude}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<BusNode> getByLatitude(@PathVariable("latitude") double latitude) {
        List<BusNode> busNode=busNodeRepository.findTop1ByLatitude(latitude);
        return busNode;
    }

    @Transactional()
    @RequestMapping(value = "/stops", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<BusStop> getBusStops() {
        BusNode busNode=busNodeRepository.findTop1ByLatitude(50.5).get(0);
        //BusNode busNode3=new BusNode();
        //busNode3.latitude=50.2;
        //busNode3.longitude=45.2;
        //busNodeRepository.save(busNode3);

        BusStop busStop=new BusStop();
        busStop.busNode=busNode;
        busStop.name="Idel";
        busStop.name_en="Idel";
        busStop.name_ru="Idel";
        busStop.name_tt="Idel";

        busStopRepository.save(busStop); // here the exception occurs
        return busStopRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

So, after the method is called, I'm getting the message that Object with id "aglidXNyb3V0ZXNyFAsSB0J1c05vZGUYgICAgICAoAgM" is managed by a different Object Manager; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Object with id "aglidXNyb3V0ZXNyFAsSB0J1c05vZGUYgICAgICAoAgM" is managed by a different Object Manager on line with         busStopRepository.save(busStop);

So how to combine the extracting of one entity from the first repository with the storage of another entity in the second repository in the same method? I have never faced the same problem in other JPA implementations.

UPD:

libraries used in pom.xml:

```
  <appengine.version>1.9.30</appengine.version>
  ...
  <!-- Spring data jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

UPD 2.

the project with the current problem can be fount on https://github.com/Eljah/busroutes-gae/tree/0.1 (tagged)

Comment: Define what is "Google AppEngine JPA" ... you mean for AppEngine/Datastore, or for some RDBMS ? (i.e Cloud SQL) and mention what version of that.

Comment: that is AppEngine datastore, based on Data Nucleus (please note the tag with it). That is not conventional RDBMS like Clous SQL

Comment: So using ancient versions of jars then, using Google's JPA provider (not DataNucleus JPA provider ... Google just uses some low level code nothing more of DataNucleus). Perhaps debug it, since you just post a load of code and don't say where (which line) that message comes from, what objects were passed in to it, what state they were in at that point, what Spring is doing with it, etc etc.

Comment: And what state are those objects in ? detached? transient? managed? I'd expect there to be a class `NucleusJPAHelper.getObjectState` that tells you (and the LOG would certainly tell you). And if they aren't detached then you have to work out why. And this likely comes down to the datastore in use (and Google's JPA provider), which does not support large parts of the JPA spec ... such as ACID transactions, etc. And the fact that it is all old versions of software (and those versions are unsupported).

Comment: what are the last DataNucleus jars compatible with GAE? I can't figure out it; the attempt to use versions other than used here https://github.com/Eljah/busroutes-gae/blob/0.1/pom.xml leads to Error executing DataNucleus tool org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer: InvocationTargetException: updateLock -> and I have to deal with this ancient jars to make possible to use JPA and Datastore with GAE.

Comment: @DN1 could you please take a look on my new question in order to direct me to a correct approach in retrieving the data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254374/how-i-can-avoid-nucleususerexception-by-obtaining-some-value-not-managed-by-an-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite I didn't got the internals of Data Nucleus and Google's JPA implementation, why I got the exceptions, I said above, I have resolved globally the problem I faced with. If you are facing the same exception it is likely that you are trying to solve the problem of reading many entities and updating few in the same transaction (since not transactional update is failing due to exceptions said above).

The problem is solved architecturally: 1) you should create separate methods in service layer for reading the entities or obtaining counts and NOT making them transactional 2) create separate methods in the service layers obtaining the results of non-transactional methods as parameters and updating the entities; make those methods transactional 3) in controller layer or in your custom layer below the controller but above the service call those methods separately!

My fault was that I supposed that Spring's @Transactional annotation makes sense even when the method with @Transactional is called from another method withot @Transactionl. That is wrong: due to Aspect nature of the annotation, they make sense only if the methods are called from outside class object. So in my examples I got the whole call being within the only transaction (with too many entities exception) or within none transaction (thus getting the Object with id ... is managed by a different Object Manager). So separating non-transactional behaviour and transactional behaviour to the different methods and calling them from outside helped me.