# How I can avoid NucleusUserException by obtaining some value not managed by an Object Manager

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

I have the business logic that requires

1) do some action like count or 'find id of top 1 item with field greater than a', i.e do some reading actions over entity A. The count or find involves more than 25 items, so it makes many Entity groups be affected.
2) then do some action on another entity B and persist the changed entity
3) now I change the only object for entity A and want to persist it

If I don't use Spring @Transactional on my method I got Object with id "A@someHash" is managed by a different Object Manager when calling 3). Ассording to System.out.println(NucleusJPAHelper.getObjectState(busRouteToCheck)); the object is in persistent state

If I use Spring @Transactional put over the whole method, I got "too many Entity groups opened in the single transaction"

How I can force results of 1) not be managed by Object Manager, to obtain finally some Long value and process 3) like I deal with A the first time in my method. Finally I need items of multiple entity groups be read and only two be updated within the transaction.

What I have tried to work around: 1) dividing use the whole method into 3 others where 2 is without @Transaction, 1 and 3 are having @Transaction; here I still got  NucleusUserException; 2) with the same condition I tried to use of 2 different transaction managers with first making calls for read-only calls (method 1) and writing with the second (method 3).

Is there any explicit way to govern the Object Manager?

Dependenciies used are:

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and enhancer plugin is

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Make sure this path contains your persistent classes! -->
                    <!--<mappingIncludes>**/domain/*.class</mappingIncludes>-->
                    <!--<persistenceUnitName>transactions-optional</persistenceUnitName>-->
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <api>JPA</api>
                    <!--<mappingIncludes>com/appspot/Player.class</mappingIncludes>-->
                    <!--<metadataIncludes>com/appspot/Player.class</metadataIncludes>-->
                    <fork>false</fork>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <!--<dependency>
                        <groupId>asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>-->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: JPA has an EntityManager not an ObjectManager, and you can detach objects with JPA

Comment: I did it (in fact I did em.close() in order to detach all objects from the Entity Manager dealing with objects from request 1), but it doesnt' help. ObjectManager is some internal from early versions of Data Nucleus.

Comment: If an object is detached then it is not in the state that you quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I got the detailed understanding of something occurring deep into google's JPA implementation and obtaining the exception I have posted. Instead I have resolved the global problem I have faced with. I believe you are facing the same problem if dealing with the exception. I tried to work around the limitations on changing some minor number of Objects within transactions and reading of may objects, where transactions are not needed (since not transactional update is failing due to exceptions said above).

The problem is solved architecturally: 1) you should create separate methods in service layer for reading the entities or obtaining counts and NOT making them transactional 2) create separate methods in the service layers obtaining the results of non-transactional methods as parameters and updating the entities; make those methods transactional 3) in controller layer or in your custom layer below the controller but above the service call those methods separately!

My fault was that I supposed that Spring's @Transactional annotation makes sense even when the method with @Transactional is called from another method withot @Transactionl. That is wrong: due to Aspect nature of the annotation, they make sense only if the methods are called from outside class object. So in my examples I got the whole call being within the only transaction (with too many entities exception) or within none transaction (thus getting the Object with id ... is managed by a different Object Manager). So separating non-transactional behaviour and transactional behaviour to the different methods and calling them from outside helped me.